# How to communicate between object instances in a "has-a" relationship (Smalltalk)?

Tags: relationship, message, smalltalk

I have been programming in Smalltalk for quite some time, but yesterday I managed to confuse myself and cannot figure out or remember how to handle this.

I have two objects in a "has-a" relationship, therefore the child object (the one that is had) is not a subclass of the owner. I cannot figure out how to message the owner and pass it some information.

To make this more concrete, the owner is a Game object and the child object is a Turn. When the turn has been completed, I need to send the turnScore to the Game instance to be added to the Game's totalScore. But, in the Turn instance, I don't see how to have a handle back to the owning Game instance. Everything I try to code errors with "message not understood".

Please help me get back on track. This should be simple. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use an event. When the turn ends, it uses self triggerEvent: #turnEnded. And in the creation, the game subscribes to the event like in turn := Turn new. turn when: #turnEnded send: #endOfTurn: to: self with: turn.

Comment: This also seems like a good candidate for the delegate pattern

Answer (score 4):

Generally, and as in any other language, you will need a reference from the Turn object to the Game object (for example in an instance variable of Turn) if you want to send it a message. Or some other means through which the Turn object can obtain a reference to the Game (singletons, mediators, service registries, ...).

Initialization could be done as follows:

```
Game》newTurn
     ^ Turn new
         game: self;
         yourself

Turn》game: aGame
     game := aGame.
```

Alternatively you could design the control flow so that the Game does not need to be called. The Game could ask the Turn for the score instead.

Another fancy approach would be to signal a ScoreNotification and handle and resume that in a method of the Game further up the call stack, if that fits the control flow. But "fancy" here probably means unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Well yes, of course. I guess my question is, "How do I get a reference to the Game instance in the Turn instance that was created by the Game instance?" Also, I consider it bad form to ask the Turn instance from the Game instance - Alan Kay once said objects should always tell other objects, not ask them.

Comment: Hmmm. The thought just hit me: maybe I can send a reference to "self" from Game when instantiating a Turn.

Comment: Ok, I'm off to try something like that. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim, yes, this is a nice solution IMHO. Because the turn will tell the game how it ended, but a turn should know of which game it is. So when a game creates a turn, it tells the turn that it's a turn of `self` (I know, in written form it looks worse than in programmed